# How to define project wide constants or how to make my own class' memberfunction accept const objects in c++

Tags: c++, class, constants, definition, linker-errors

In my C++ project I've got a number of constants that I want to access from different classes . I put them all into a .h file that I named constants.h (I am not sure if this is the best idea, but it helped me keeping things sorted)
Now I have the problem, that if I include that in more than one cpp file, I get LNK2005 errors:

> ------ Build started: Project: testMy3Dpoints, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   Compiling...
>   testMy3Dpoints.cpp
>   Linking...
>   calculateDotproduct.obj : error LNK2005: "int myint" (?myint@@3HA) already defined in TestMy3Dpoints.obj
>   calculateDotproduct.obj : error LNK2005: "class v3d vect2" (?vect2@@3Vv3d@@A) already defined in testMy3Dpoints.obj
>   calculateDotproduct.obj : error LNK2005: "class v3d vect1" (?vect1@@3Vv3d@@A) already defined in testMy3Dpoints.obj
>   D:\3D mapping\visual studio projects\testMy3Dpoints\Debug\testMy3Dpoints.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

When I was using only integers, defining all the variables as const made these errors disappear an the program compiled and run fine. 
But since I started introducing constants that are objects of my class v3d, this yields a different error:
error C2662: 'v3d::dotProduct' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const v3d' to 'v3d &'       Conversion loses qualifiers
Apparently it doesn't like cons v3d variables (constants).  Is there anything wrong in the way I define the member function v3d::dotProduct?

This is my code:

testMy3Dpoints.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "v3d.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include "calculateDotproduct.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


double dp = vect1.dotProduct(vect2);

std::cout << "myint: " << myint << std::endl;
std::cout << "vect1.x " << vect1.x << ", vect1.y " << vect1.y << ", vect1.z " << vect1.z << std::endl;
std::cout << "vect2.x " << vect2.x << ", vect2.y " << vect2.y << ", vect2.z " << vect2.z << std::endl;
std::cout << "dp = " << dp << std::endl;

alsoCalculateDotProduct();

return 0;
```

}

calculateDotproduct.h

```
#pragma once
void alsoCalculateDotProduct(

calculateDotproduct.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "v3d.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include "calculateDotproduct.h"

void alsoCalculateDotProduct()
{
double mydp = vect1.dotProduct(vect2);

std::cout << "vect1.x " << vect1.x << ", vect1.y " << vect1.y << ", vect1.z " << vect1.z << std::endl;
std::cout << "vect2.x " << vect2.x << ", vect2.y " << vect2.y << ", vect2.z " << vect2.z << std::endl;
std::cout << "mydp = " << mydp << std::endl;

return;
}
```

v3d.h:

```
#pragma once

class v3d
{
public:
double x;
double y;
double z;
v3d(double a, double b, double c);
void set(double a, double b, double c);
double dotProduct(v3d vector);
};
```

v3d.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "v3d.h"    
void v3d::set(double a, double b, double c)
{
x=a;
y=b;
z=c;
}
v3d::v3d(double a, double b, double c)
{
set(a,b,c);
}
double v3d::dotProduct(v3d vector)
{
return x*vector.x + y*vector.y + z*vector.z;
}
```

constants.h

```
#pragma once 
#include "v3d.h"
const v3d vect1(1, 2, 3.14);
const  v3d vect2(4, 1.5, 0);
const int myint = 3;
```

respectively

```
#pragma once 
#include "v3d.h"
v3d vect1(1, 2, 3.14);
v3d vect2(4, 1.5, 0);
int myint = 3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object with external linkage must be defined once.  In

```
v3d vect1(1, 2, 3.14);
```

vect1 has external linkage.  So you'd have to use

```
extern V3d vect1;
```

in the .h and then

```
v3d vect1(1, 2, 3.14);
```

in *one* .cpp.  There is a special rules which makes

```
const int myint = 3;
```

have internal linkage if it is never used as a lvalue, which could happen unexpectedly it is fed as a reference parameter or in something like:

```
x = v ? myint : myint2;
```

(Note that in general global variables are frowned upon).

Comment: Thank you for your advise. The program compiles and runs now.
However, defining my vectors vect1 and vect2 as variables (as opposed to constants) and then assign a value in a cpp file defeats my idea of having one file where all the constants are stored.

Comment: Background: I want to store the positions of parts of a robot in vect1 and vect2. These values have to be accessible from every cpp file of my project.
For a different configuration of the robot, I would just change these vectors without touching anything else of the program. Therefore gathering all the constants in the constants.h file would make my code much more clear. 
Isn't there a way to assign values to my vectors in the constants.h file?

Comment: >>(Note that in general global variables are frowned upon).

I know, but as these are parameters of my system that I have to access  from different cpp files I didn't see any better option. Do you have a better idea?
As it were constants in the first place I thought it is excusable..

Comment: C++0X constexpr is what your are waiting for.  Waiting for that, I see no solution worse than what you want to avoid. Giving them internal linkage (static, anonymous namespace) would allow you to put the definition in the header without duplicate problem -- because there are none: each TU has its  variables.  Using templates or inline functions, you may give a definition in each TU -- at the cost of code obfuscation.

Comment: Ok, then there doesn't seem to be a neat solution at this moment. If I understand you rigth, C++0x's constexpr would also allow me to have const double mydouble2 = vect1.dotProduct(vect2); in my constants.h header file. For the time being I moved the declaration and definition of mydouble2 into the cpp file where I'm using it. This is a little waste of performance because it is evaluated at runtime even thought it could be done at compiling time, but I guess I won't notice the difference.